# angularjs custom made service not working with arrow "=>" function?

Tags: angularjs

I am practicing using angularjs with custom made service but when I use arrow functions on service() it's not working, can someone help me with this please....

here is my sample code with custom service and arrow function:

```
    <script>
        const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.service('getNameService', () =>{
            this.getSomething = () => {
                return 'something';
            }
        });
        app.controller('myCtrl', ($scope, getNameService) => {
            $scope.test = getNameService.getSomething();
        });
    </script>
```

this code to show:

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <h2>{{test}}</h2>
```

how can I use arrow function with angularjs custom made service() ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of ES6. Also go through that page for more details [here](https://blog.cloudboost.io/es-6-essentials-for-angular-10391da40fd6) , these are the things that essentials for Angularjs.

But by the use of **Babel or Traceur** you can able to do it.
You can also try these:

[ES 6 essentials for Angular](https://blog.cloudboost.io/es-6-essentials-for-angular-10391da40fd6)

[fix(injector): support arrow functions with no parenthesis](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/03726f7fbd5d71c0604b8dd40e97cb2fb0fb777f)

[fix($injector): Allows ES6 function syntax](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/44a96a4c140873d9fd8484d870af83a0bb9acabd)

[When (and why) you should use ES6 arrow functions — and when you shouldn’t](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26)

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: The website linked in your anwser is about `Angular`, which is not the same as `AngularJS`